# Why is the covariance matrix of the OLS regression error written as $\mathrm{E}({\bf e}{\bf e^\prime} | {\bf X})$?

Tags: regression, residuals, covariance-matrix

In [Hansen (2016)](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf) I read that the conditional covariance matrix of the regression error $\bf e$ is $\mathrm{E}({\bf e}{\bf e^\prime} | {\bf X})$.

How is this related to the [covariance formula](http://covariance%20formula): 
$$cov({\bf X}{\bf Y} = \mathrm{E}({\bf X}{\bf Y^\prime}) - E({\bf X})E({\bf Y})^\prime \qquad?$$

Why is the "expectation" notation  used and how is it justified mathematically?

Answer (score 2):

The covariance formula is the definition of covariance. It is equivalent to the definition of the conditional covariance matrix for regression error:

$$\mbox{cov}(XY)=E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])']=E[XY']-E[X]E[Y]',$$

and generalizes to conditional covariance $|Z$ by throwing in a $|Z$ into every expectation above. Thus, since

$$E[e|X]=0,$$

you have:
$$\mbox{cov}(ee'|X)=E[(e-E[e|X])(e-E[e|X])'|X]=E[ee'|X].$$